# Find all records in DNS zone without zone transfer enabled

Tags: domain-name-system

Is there any way of finding out a total list of `A` and `CNAME` records for a domain if Zone Transfer is disabled?

Client is Windows, and I've already tried `ls -d example.com` in `nslookup` (hence how I know Zone Transfer is disabled).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no method for doing this. This is specifically why Zone transfer is to be disabled to untrusted DNS peers - To prevent discovery of the entire DNS topology.

Answer (score 4):

Chris Thorpe and einstieen are right in 99.99 % of the cases. There is no way.

In very rare cases, there is another method: NSEC walking. If the zone is signed with DNSSEC (something that will be more and more common now that the [root is signed](http://www.root-dnssec.org/)), **and** if it is signed with NSEC, not NSEC3, **and** if there is no rate-limiting in place, you may walk the entire zone. See an [explanation and implementation](http://josefsson.org/walker/). (There is an [alternative implementation](http://www.nlnetlabs.nl/svn/ldns/trunk/examples/ldns-walk.c) using [ldns](http://www.nlnetlabs.nl/projects/ldns/)).

Answer (score 2):

I'm 99% certain there isn't a way. I've actually made an argument on here against AXFR for this very reason. The only thing I can think of is brute forcing it, but that may seem a little cumbersome and unnecessary depending on why you need to.